# C++ std::optional implementation

Tags: c++, reinventing-the-wheel, c++20, optional

Took a shot at implementing a subset of `std::optional` functionality. A lot of core features are there but some things like converting constructors, etc are missing as I just wanted to focus on the basic ideas.

The implementation:

```
#include <compare>
#include <typeinfo>
#include <utility>

struct BadOptionalAccess : std::exception {
    const char* what() const noexcept override {
        return "Tried to access an Optional()'s value, but no value exists!";
    }
};


template<typename T>
class Optional {
public:
    Optional() noexcept {
        std::memset(m_data, 0, sizeof(T));
    }

    Optional(const T& value) : 
        m_has_value{true} {
            new (m_data) T(value);
        }
    
    template<typename... Args>
    Optional(std::in_place_t, Args&&... args) {
        emplace(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }
    
    Optional(const Optional& other) : 
        m_has_value{other.m_has_value} {
            if (other.m_has_value) {
                new(m_data) T(other.value());
            }
        }
    
    Optional(Optional&& other) noexcept : 
        m_has_value{other.m_has_value} {
            if (other.has_value()) {
                new(m_data) T(std::move(other.value()));
                other.m_has_value = false;
            }
        }
    
    Optional& operator=(const Optional& other) {
        Optional temp {other};
        temp.swap(*this);
        return *this;
    }

    Optional& operator=(Optional&& other) noexcept {
        Optional temp {std::move(other)};
        temp.swap(*this);
        
        return *this;
    }

    auto operator<=>(const Optional& other) const noexcept {
        if (!has_value() && !other.has_value()) {
            return std::strong_ordering::equal;
        } else if (!has_value() && other.has_value()) {
            return std::strong_ordering::less;
        } else if (has_value() && !other.has_value()) {
            return std::strong_ordering::greater;
        } else {
            return value() <=> other.value();
        }
    }

    bool operator==(const Optional& other) const noexcept {
        return (*this <=> other) == std::strong_ordering::equal;
    }

    bool operator!=(const Optional& other) const noexcept {
        return !(*this == other);
    }

    explicit operator bool() const noexcept {
        return has_value();
    }
    
    template<typename... Args>
    void emplace(Args&&... args) {
        reset();
        new (m_data) T(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
        m_has_value = true;
    }

    template<typename U>
    T value_or(U&& default_value) {
        return has_value() ? std::move(**this) 
            : static_cast<T>(std::forward<U>(default_value));
    }

    void reset() {
        if (m_has_value) {
            T* val = reinterpret_cast<T*>(m_data);
            val->~T();
            m_has_value = false;
        }
    }

    void swap(Optional& other) noexcept {
        // Do I need to do this? My first instinct was to do
        // an ordinary swap of the m_data's, but it seemed wrong 
        // to do in case the types weren't trivially copyable/movable.
        // Maybe I should special case in those situations?
        if (other.has_value() && has_value()) {
            std::swap(*reinterpret_cast<T*>(m_data), *reinterpret_cast<T*>(other.m_data));
        } else if (other.has_value()) {
            new (m_data) T(std::move(other.value()));
        } else if (has_value()) {
            new(other.m_data) T(std::move(value()));
        }
        
        std::swap(m_has_value, other.m_has_value);
    }

    bool has_value() const noexcept {
        return m_has_value;
    }

    const T& value() const {
        return *ptr();
    }

    const T& operator*() const& {
        return value();
    }

    const T* operator->() const {
        return ptr();
    }

    T& value() {
        return *ptr();
    }

    T& operator*() & {
        return value();
    }

    T&& operator*() && noexcept {
        return std::move(value());
    }

    const T&& operator*() const&& noexcept {
        // not 100% sure how to use/test this overload. Why would an rvalue be const?
        return std::move(**this);
    }

    T* operator->() {
        return ptr();
    }

    ~Optional() {
        reset();
    }
        

private:
    alignas(T) unsigned char m_data[sizeof(T)];
    bool m_has_value = false;

    const T* ptr() const {
        if (!m_has_value) {
            throw BadOptionalAccess();
        }

        return (reinterpret_cast<const T*>(m_data));
    }

    T* ptr() {
        if (!m_has_value) {
            throw BadOptionalAccess();
        }

        return (reinterpret_cast<T*>(m_data));
    }
};

template<typename T, typename... Args>
Optional<T> makeOptional(Args&&... args) {
    return Optional<T>(std::in_place, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

Some tests:

````
#define BOOST_TEST_MODULE optionaltest

#ifdef BOOST_TEST_DYN_LINK
#include <boost/test/unit_test.hpp>
#else
#include <boost/test/included/unit_test.hpp>
#endif // BOOST_TEST_DYN_LINK

#include <boost/test/data/monomorphic.hpp>
#include <boost/test/data/test_case.hpp>

#include "Optional.h"
#include <string>



BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(default_constructor_test) {
    Optional<int> o;
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(basic_constructors_test) {
     Optional<int> o1;
     Optional<int> o2 = 1;
     Optional<int> o3 = o2;
 
    // calls std::string( size_type count, CharT ch ) constructor
    Optional<std::string> o4(std::in_place, 3, 'A');
    Optional<std::string> o5 = makeOptional<std::string>(3, 'A');

    BOOST_CHECK(o4==o5);
 
    // Move-constructed from std::string using deduction guide to pick the type
    Optional o6(std::string{"deduction very long type"});
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(access_operator_test) {
    using namespace std::string_literals;

    Optional<int> opt1 = 1;
    BOOST_CHECK_EQUAL(*opt1, 1);
 
    *opt1 = 2;
    BOOST_CHECK_EQUAL(*opt1, 2);
 
    Optional<std::string> opt2 = "abc"s;
    BOOST_CHECK_EQUAL(*opt2, "abc"s);
    BOOST_CHECK_EQUAL(opt2->size(), 3); 
 
    Optional<std::string> taken = std::move(opt2);
    BOOST_CHECK_EQUAL(*taken, "abc"s); 
    BOOST_CHECK_EQUAL(taken->size(), 3); 

    BOOST_CHECK(!opt2.has_value()); 
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(value_check_test) {
    Optional<int> opt;
    BOOST_CHECK(!opt.has_value());
 
    opt = 43;
    BOOST_CHECK(opt.has_value());

    if (opt) {
        BOOST_CHECK(true);
    } else {
        BOOST_CHECK(false);
    }

    opt.reset();
    BOOST_CHECK(!opt.has_value());
}


BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(get_value_test) {
    Optional<int> opt = {};

    BOOST_CHECK_THROW(opt.value(), BadOptionalAccess);
    BOOST_CHECK_THROW(opt.value() = 42, BadOptionalAccess);

    opt = 43;
    BOOST_CHECK_EQUAL(*opt, 43);
    BOOST_CHECK_EQUAL(opt.value(), 43);
    
    opt.value() = 44;
    BOOST_CHECK_EQUAL(*opt, 44);
    BOOST_CHECK_EQUAL(opt.value(), 44); 
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(ValueOrTest) {
    // Test with existing value
    Optional<int> opt1(5);
    BOOST_CHECK_EQUAL(opt1.value_or(10), 5);

    // Test without an existing value
    Optional<int> opt2; // Empty optional
    BOOST_CHECK_EQUAL(opt2.value_or(10), 10);

    // Test with a different type
    Optional<double> opt3; // Empty optional
    BOOST_CHECK_CLOSE(opt3.value_or(10), 10.0, 0.0001); // BOOST_CHECK_CLOSE for floating point comparison

    // Test with rvalue when Optional has a value
    Optional<std::string> opt4("Hello");
    BOOST_CHECK_EQUAL(opt4.value_or(std::string("World")), "Hello");

    // Test with rvalue when Optional does not have a value
    Optional<std::string> opt5; // Empty optional
    BOOST_CHECK_EQUAL(opt5.value_or(std::string("World")), "World");
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(swap_test) {
    Optional<std::string> opt1("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur tincidunt.");
    Optional<std::string> opt2("Some other lorem ipsum");

    opt1.swap(opt2);
    BOOST_CHECK_EQUAL(*opt2, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur tincidunt.");
    BOOST_CHECK_EQUAL(*opt1, "Some other lorem ipsum");

    opt1.reset();
    opt1.swap(opt2);

    BOOST_CHECK_EQUAL(*opt1, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur tincidunt.");
    BOOST_CHECK(!opt2.has_value());
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(comparison_test) {
    Optional<int> o1, o2;
    BOOST_CHECK(o1 == o2);

    o2.emplace(10);
    BOOST_CHECK(o1 < o2);
    BOOST_CHECK(o2 > o1);
    BOOST_CHECK(o2 != o1);

    o1.emplace(10);
    BOOST_CHECK(o1 == o2);
    BOOST_CHECK(o1 <= o2);
    BOOST_CHECK(o1 >= o2);
}
```
````

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Missing `#include`s

You are missing `#include <cstring>` for `std::memset()`, and `#include <new>` for the placement `new` operator.

## The converting constructors are a core feature

You have a non-converting constructor, but that does not even exist in `std::optional`. I would say that this is a core feature. Without it, you will get apparently inconsistent and surprising behavior. Consider:

```
Optional<int> foo = 3.1415;                  // works
Optional<float> bar = 42;                    // works
Optional<std::string> baz = "Hello, world!"; // fails to compile
```

The first two statements will happily cause conversions to happen. Fixing this so the third statement also compiles is trivial:

```
Optional(const auto& value) : 
    m_has_value{true} {
        new (m_data) T(value);
    }
```

I am very surprised by the choice of "basic features"; you have implemented `operator<=>()`, but I have never seen any code using the relational operators on `std::optional`s.

## Unnecessary zeroing of memory in the default constructor

The default constructor does not need to zero `m_data[]`, it's just going to cost you performance.

## The move constructor should not unset `other.m_has_value`

In the move constructor, you set `other.m_has_value` to `false`, but you don't call the destructor of the other's value. And since the destructor of `other` will then not destruct its `m_has_value`, you will have created an object which will never be destructed propery.

You must leave `other` in a state such that everything will eventually be correctly destructed. However, as Igor G mentioned, [`std::optional`'s specification](https://eel.is/c++draft/optional.ctor#9) says that after a move construction, `other.has_value()` should not return a different value than before the move construction. So the best thing to do is to just not set `other.m_has_value = false` at all.

## Incorrect behavior of `swap()`

Related to the above: you have a similar problem in `swap()`, in case you swap an optional which has a value with one which hasn't. Here you have to explicitly call `reset()` on the side which will no longer have a value after the swap.

## About swapping

> ```
> // Do I need to do this? My first instinct was to do
> // an ordinary swap of the m_data's, but it seemed wrong 
> // to do in case the types weren't trivially copyable/movable.
> // Maybe I should special case in those situations?
> ```

You did the right thing in the code. You can't just swap the `m_data`s, that would just swap bytes without checking if that is legal, and would also bypass any specializations of `std::swap` for `T`. And in case `T` is trivially copyable/movable, then `std::swap<T>` would do exactly the same as `std::swap<decltype<m_data>>`, so there is no need to make this a special case.

Comment: Thanks @G. Sliepen for the help! As for how I chose "basic features", I just went onto cppreference.com, looked at the API, and tried to implement most of those things (but not necessarily all possible overloads of them), but I can see how not having a converting constructor was an oversight.

Comment: The `(const auto&)` constructor is a revelation, thanks for explaining it! Very useful that it checks if the conversion is possible so you can't do things like `std::optional<std:string> op = 7;`. But it seems not to be sufficient on its own, I get errors if I don't have the `(const T&)` constructor as well. Is there a name this goes by or any resource you recommend to read more about how this works? Thanks!

Comment: "The move constructor should destroy the other's value" -- should it?

Comment: @IgorG Well it could also leave it up to `other`'s destructor to destruct the value stored in `other`. So then `other.m_has_value` should not be set to `false`, or some other state has to be added to track "has no value but there's still a live `T` object that needs to be destroyed".

Comment: @jdav22 You probably also need to implement a constructor that takes anything by r-value reference: `Optional(auto&& value)`. Those are [converting constructors](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/converting_constructor).

Comment: @jdav22, "Very useful that it checks if the conversion is possible" -- I'm afraid there could be some misunderstanding here. The prototype `Optional(const auto&)` in itself doesn't check for any conversion. It does what it says: it accepts a single argument of any type. Try `std::is_convertible<int, Optional<std::string>>::value` and see that it's `true`. You must write explicit requirements to enable this constructor only for compatible argument types.

Comment: @IgorG I see what you mean. I made the comment because I tried `Optional<std::string> bar = 7;` which failed with a compiler error, but the error is `no matching function for call to ‘std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>::basic_string(const int&)`. So it's not that the converting constructor constrains this, rather `std::string` has no constructor which accepts an `int.`

Comment: However, I think the `(const auto&)` constructor is then too lenient. After some searching I think something like this gives me the level of constraint I want: 

`template<typename U>
    requires(std::is_constructible_v<T, const U&> &&
            !std::is_same_v<std::decay_t<U>, T> &&
            !std::is_same_v<std::decay_t<U>, Optional<T>>)
    Optional(const U& value);`

This also makes `static_assert(std::is_convertible<int, Optional<std::string>>::value)` `false`, which is what I would have expected. It's only true with the overly lenient converting constructor.

Answer (score 5):

## Casting a storage to an object requires `std::launder()`

Since this question is tagged `C++20`, lines like this one:

```
return (reinterpret_cast<T*>(m_data));
```

should really be

```
return std::launder(reinterpret_cast<T*>(m_data));
```

## Don't forget to set `m_has_value` every time you construct a new object.

Construction of `T` in `m_data` happens in many places, and sometimes it isn't accompanied by setting `m_has_value` to `true`. This kind of errors can be avoided if all construction was factored out to a single private function.

```
} else if (other.has_value()) {
    new (m_data) T(std::move(other.value()));
    // Hey, the object is there, but m_has_value is still false!
} else if ........
```

## If moved-from optional contained some value before the move, it must still contain a value after the move

If an Optional contains a value, then every `move` should be performed on that contained value *only*.

```
Optional<int>      src = 42;
Optional<int>      dst(std::move(src));
assert( src.has_value() );
```

So, this line should be removed from constructor:

```
other.m_has_value = false;    // Wrong!
```

## `operator*` and `operator->` must be noexcept

Which means they cannot throw. Hence, they may not call neither `value()` nor `ptr()`.

```
T& operator*() & {
    return value();   // That function may throw!
}
```

## Don't underestimate SFINAE

Optional constructors and operators must participate in overload resolution only if certain conditions are met (read: they must be heavily loaded with SFINAE code checking those conditions). Getting all those conditions right isn't easy and requires lots of tests.

Comment: Yes, not setting `other.m_has_value = false` is also a valid way to move from. The main point is that the contents of `other` don't really matter, as long as it is in a valid enough state so `other` and its members are destroyed correctly at some point.

Comment: @G.Sliepen, I thought that this behavior is required by the Standard, note "rhs.has_value() is unchanged" requirement in https://eel.is/c++draft/optional.ctor#9

Comment: Ah! I didn't know it was part of `std::optional`'s spec. I wonder why they did this though, normally when you move from an object, you shouldn't access it anymore anyway, so you'd think that the result of `has_value()` shouldn't matter.

Comment: @G.Sliepen, "when you move from an object, you shouldn't access it anymore" -- that's generally true, but as a special case of "access" you're allowed to **assign new value** to a moved-from object. That's what `vector<movable_type>` does all the time :- ) So my guess is that such behavior was specified to make `optional_a = move(optional_b); optional_b = move(optional_c);` as close to `a = move(b); b = move(c)` as possible. Just guessing.

Comment: Thanks @IgorG for the help! I've previously heard of `std::launder` but have not 100% understood why it was needed, but this clarifies it for me. Thanks also for pointing out the non-conformance of destroying the T in the moved-from object. So the expectation is, when you move the value from `rhs` and `rhs` gets destroyed later on, then only the "moved-from" state of `T` is destroyed, guaranteeing you don't destroy something twice while still keeping `has_value()` the same - is my understanding correct?

Comment: @jdav22, "when you move the value from rhs and rhs gets destroyed later on, then only the moved-from state of T is destroyed, guaranteeing you don't destroy something twice" -- yes, exactly.

Answer (score 3):

You have a lot of repeated, low level code.  Create some `private` `unsafe_` methods to avoid that repetition.

```
template<class...Ts>
void unsafe_emplace(Ts&&...ts);
void unsafe_destroy();
T* unsafe_get();
T const* unsafe_get() const;
```

these contain your `reintepret_cast`s, `std::launder`s, `::new( (void*)m_data )`, `->~T()`s.

They do absolutely no checking - that is what `unsafe_` is for - and they are private.

Now your public methods:

```
void reset() {
  if (m_has_value) {
    unsafe_destroy();
  }
}
```

no longer fiddle around with the low-level operations.

The only "safe" thing the `unsafe_` functions do is assign to `m_has_value` for destroy/emplace.  They do not check the value before they operate.

And they work together:

```
void unsafe_destroy() {
  unsafe_get()->~T();
  m_has_value = false;
}
```

the reason I skip checking `m_has_value` is that reasonably often you'll know if it is true or not prior to calling these operations, and what to do when you get it wrong is either complex or nonsense.

Adding asserts is good however:

```
void unsafe_destroy() {
  assert(m_has_value);
  unsafe_get()->~T();
  m_has_value = false;
}
```

a second benefit is that when you are using placement new, you want to use `::new` and cast its argument to `void*` to avoid the possibility that you hit an accidental manual override.  By having your placement new code be in exactly one spot, fixing it in a bunch of spots stops being a problem.

Comment: Thanks @Yakk for the help! Didn't think about how people's overrides of the `new` operator could do finicky things to mess with placement new, good thing to keep in mind.